# Run both php and python at the same time on google app engine

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, runtime

I heard that this was possible using the new modules features for the google app engine, but this will require two different modules, which basically is like two different apps. I would like to be able to run my python and php in the same application. Im getting some results via python and I want to parse them using php to get an API that is able to communicate with my other webapplications online. it will be like a proxy between my python scripts and webapplication. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, no. You'll have to use separate modules, or pick one language and use it for both of the things you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Segregate your applications in different modules and communicate between the two using the GAE Data Store or Memcache.

Your applications can signal each other using a GET request with the name of the Memcache key or the url safe data store key.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the proxy pattern by simply making http requests from one module to the other, using the URLFetch service.